# Got Everpad Installed and working - Alas cannot search in dash

Tags: 13.10, unity-dash, lenses, everpad

I got Everpad installed and syncing, however everpad lens does appear in the dash. Therefore I am unable to search my note. 
Using Ubuntu 13.10 and Everpad (version: 2.5 API version: 6 Schema version: 5)

Answer (score 1):

lens api for python in ubuntu 13.10 broken, you can vote for this bug - https://bugs.launchpad.net/singlet/+bug/1248050